# Hosting WCF on IIS6, does it require any special setup?

Tags: wcf, configuration, iis-6

Does hosting a WCF service require any special configuration on IIS6?

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/amitlale/archive/2007/05/21/hosting-wcf-service-in-iis.aspx) is a pretty handy blog post for your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ServiceHostReg of WCF:

The tool can be found in the following location:

```
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\
```

The command line is:

```
ServiceHostReg /x /i
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) VirtualDirectoryName->Properties->Virtual Directory Tab->Confirguration Button->

Insert new WildCard Mapping C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll Uncheck Verify that file exists

Step 2)

VirtualDirectoryName->Properties->Directory Security Tab->Authentication and access control->Edit Button->

Uncheck Integrated Windodws Authentication

Step3) Reset IIS